# Print php`s object data in specific order

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, lumen

```
<?php $days = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thur','fri','sat'];?>

                    @for($i=0;$i<count($days);$i++)

                        <label>{{$days[$i]}}:</label>

                        @for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>From:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="{{$days[$i]}}[{{$j}}][start]" type="text" value="">
                                <label>To:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="{{$days[$i]}}[{{$j}}][end]" type="text" value="">
                            </div>

                        @endfor

                    @endfor
```

The above code prints html form from sunday to saturday with 4 input fields for each days:
[image: htmlform]

I have passed a collection object from the controller to the view with $data as a variable name. So in the $data variable I have the fetched rows from databased which matched the selection.
I want to be able to print the fetched values in the input fields.
For eg: For sunday i want to only print the value belonging to sunday in the input field and so forth.And in the database the value of day is simply 1 for sunday to 7 for saturday.Here is the output of $data:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `$data` var_dump so that we can know its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of hair pulling I finally found the solution.
My view code

```
<div id="sample1" class="ui-widget-content" style="padding: .5em;">
                    <?php $days = [1=>'sun','mon','tue','wed','thur','fri','sat'];?>
                    @for($i=1;$i<=count($days);$i++)
                        <label>{{$days[$i]}}:</label>
                            <?php $j =0; ?>
                            @foreach($datas as $data)
                                    @if($data->day_id == $i)
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>From:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="{{$days[$i]}}[{{$j}}][start]" type="text" value="{{$data->start}}">
                                <label>To:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="{{$days[$i]}}[{{$j}}][end]" type="text" value="{{$data->end}}">
                            </div>
                                        <?php $j++?>
                                    @endif
                            @endforeach
                    @endfor
                </div>
```

My controller code.

```
public function editRoutine($schedule_id, $group_id)
    {
        $data = $this->routineModel->where('schedule_id',$schedule_id)->where('group_id',$group_id)->get();
        /*foreach($data as $t){
            dump($t->toArray());
        }
        die;*/
        return view('admin.routine.editRoutine',[
                'datas'=>$data
        ]);
    }
```